# How to set the consent url for an Identity server OAuth login

Tags: identityserver4

In all the IS4 quickstart demos, the consent Url is /consent. Is there a way/place to set that?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the options Api provided on the `IIdentityServerBuilder` interface. In other words, when registering with DI use the below:

```
services.AddIdentityServer(options =>
            {
                options.UserInteraction.ConsentUrl  = "Your consent Url";
            })
```